# Documenting port numbers on floor plan

Tags: networking, documentation

I want to be able to create a simple floor plan and document where all the ports are located and what there number is.

Is there any good software to help with this.  Preferably open source / free.

Comment: Are you looking for floor plan software?  Nothing automated is going to be able to document the network drops for you.

Comment: Any CAD software can do that. Ideally you would get the plan as a drawing file and edit it using the appropriate software.

Answer (score 4):

This is a job that will require you to first walk around the office and document with pen and paper. Once that's done you can use something like Visio or SmartDraw or gliffy to make your drawings/ floor plans.

Comment: Re-reading this, I think he wants floor plan software: something like Visio, but with symbols/tools to make it easier to document the floor plan.

Comment: Oh. I misunderstood then. My bad. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm making an assumption you're looking for floor plan software.  The only one I know of that's open source is [here](http://www.sweethome3d.com/index.jsp).  It's geared towards the home owner, but you can do basic wall/window/door structures.

Other option may be to obtain a digital copy or scan in the floor plan for your office and edit it in something like GIMP.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified what OS you're using but if it's Windows you can use [Dia](http://projects.gnome.org/dia/) for this. While it's not made for this kind of drawing it is still very usable. It's also great for many other diagramming jobs.